# How to specify custom Loss function for Predict

Tags: machine-learning

How can I use Predict[Xs->Ys, Method->"NeuralNetwork"] to predict 90%-quantile (instead of  mean value)?

Utility Function does not work well for this case, because

1. it assumes NormalDistribution
2. it uses same sigma for all samples
3. It takes long time to calculate 90%-quantile using Predict with UtilityFunction -> quantile loss

```
Q90Loss1[x_] := If[x >= 0, 0.9 x, -0.1 x];
model[samples, UtilityFunction -> Q90Loss1[#1 - #2]]
```

Example:

```
data = Table[Random[], 1000];
target = (# + 0.3 Random[]) & /@ data;
Q90Loss1[x_] := If[x >= 0, 0.9 x, -0.1 x];
Q90Loss[predict_, target_] := Plus @@ (Q90Loss1 /@ (target - predict));

(* best predict for this Loss is  data + 0.3 * 0.9 *)
predict = data + 0.3 * 0.9;
Q90Loss[predict, target]

(* NMinimize do the job (but I want use NeuralNetworks for more complex data) *)
NMinimize[
 {
  Q90Loss[ pA * data + pB, target],
  pA >=  0.5, pA <= 1.2, pB >= 0, pB <= 1
  },
 {pA, pB}
 ]
(* {13.4178, {pA -> 0.98412, pB -> 0.277795}} *)
```

Predict predicts NormalDistribution (instead of  UniformDistribution):

```
model = Predict[data -> target, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
model[data[[1]], "Distribution"]

(* NormalDistribution[0.527893, 0.0954062] *)
```